# sdb: device unauthorized. Please approve on your device

Tags: tizen

Trying to connect to the Gear S2 from sbd version 2.3.0.

```
$ sdb connect 192.168.1.10
sdb: device unauthorized. Please approve on your device
```

What does this mean?

Comment: You should provide screenshot also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a long running bug in the command line tool. I usually get it on first run. It appears that the command line tool will report a status while the connection process is still going on.

Getting assurances that the server has connected is always good, and one way to get that is to **simply run the command line twice in a row**.  For me it's always given a truer response a second time.

Also, **if you have a lock screen on your watch** (which you will if you have Samsung Pay active on the watch) you will receive this message **if the screen has relocked**. Reasons for frequent re-locking are:

- A watch with the lock screen outside of the cradle it might lock frequently if you handle the watch
- The heart rate sensor on the back of the watch can re-lock the watch if your finger passes in front of it since the watch may you think you just took it off

Comment: indeed, running the command a second time is how i learned that i can ignore that message. thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: Holy crap, running the connect command does indeed show that it's already connected. I am continually surprised at how painful it is working on Tizen.